# regex and variables in sql query

Tags: sql, regex, variables, sql-like

I am trying to search for a word in a paragraph: 
  `WHERE paragraph LIKE '%$term%'` 
  but then if i'm searching "in" as `$term` i'll also get "against", "reading" etc. so i want $term between spaces. `% $term %` doesn't seem to work and the term can be before or after punctuation signs. 
 I read about `RLIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE`, but is it possible to use regular expression around a variable?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: i think just use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE` (source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: that doesn't work. The problem is the dollar sign has a meaning in regular expressions so i'm not sure how to include the variable

Comment: where are these variables coming from? are you in the MySQL command line client, or a PHP script, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysqli [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from table where paragraph regexp ?")
$stmt->bind_param('s', "[,. ]{$term}[,. ]")
```